# How do I build the window manager of cinnamon?

Tags: 20.04

I do have the latest version of Ubuntu (desktop 20.04), with the cinnamon desktop installed.
Now I would like to build the window manager, and install it, preferably as an new entry, so the default, pre-compiled one stays an option. Does anyone know how I can do this?